# TCL: detect string map substitution

Tags: string, replace, tcl

I have a question about the use of `string map` in TCL.
Is there a way to detect when this function has changed the previous value of the mapped string?
For example, in this case:

```
set location "default_user: admin"
set new_user "user"
set new_location [string map [list "admin" $new_user] $location]
```

In this case, I want to know if `new_location` has a different value than `location` (without comparing both variables, maybe there is a more elegant way).
My real case is more complicated than this one, I have a variable with the content of a html file, and I want to substitute a specific value for another one or read from another variable if there was no subtitution.

Thanks for your help, I hope everything is clear in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string map` function does not imply a return number of replacements. In order to get the number of substitutions may be used `regsub -all` function that returns the value. You can also use a `string first` to value before `string map`, to learn whether there is a variable line of the desired value.

Comment: Thank you Chpock, you are right. I was now trying to solve the issue using regexp (in order to check if there was the pattern before substitution) and string first is also a good choice, good to know.
I think that doing the replacement in a single statement with string map is just not possible.